# ASP.Net MVC Application cannot find home index page on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, indexing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I deployed a MVC web application with razor view to godaddy.com. My application works fine on localhost, but after deployed, it cannot route to my home page when I typed in the domain name. I have the following route registered in my Global.axcs file.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "HomePage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Godaddy's technical supports asked me to add an index.html file in the root. I did add one and comment the default route in Global. And it loads the index.html. But I really want to display my /HomePage/Index

Does anyone know why this happens, and any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced a similar issue in the past.

One issue here might be that your server does not have MVC installed (as in my case).

Resolution : I followed the post to bin deploy the MVC assemblies together with my web application.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

**It worked for me.**

Give it a try and I think it should work.